# Phonegap 2.7 iPhone Torch fail

Tags: iphone, cordova

I need a torch on my phonegap project (Cordova 2.7.0, xcode 4.6.2), but I cannot activate it on iPhone. I've tested 2 solutions:

1. [The shazron plugin](https://github.com/shazron/TorchPlugin), but it refuses to compile with a lot of errors, even using it's javacript upgrade (include in next solution)
2. [Tom Schreck's upgrade](https://github.com/tomschreck/iOS-Torch-Plugin). It did't throw any error, but it fails too. I've tested it on older versions of phonegap, such 2.2.0 with same results.

Any suggestion??
Thanks!

Comment: What errors are you getting exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tom's solution has erros in the demo file. At least, to toggle the torch you can use `window.plugins.torch.toggle();` but it only works in Cordova 2.2.0. ¿Any update for Cordova 2.7.0?